# Add a custom text before the price display in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

In WooCommerce, I'm using this code to put a text in the price display:

```
function cw_change_product_price_display( $price ) {
    $price .= ' TEXT';
    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );
```

The page displays like `"$99,99 TEXT"`

I want to make it displays like this: `"TEXT $99,99"`

Thank you for the help.

Comment: `$price = 'TEXT '.$price;`

Comment: Worked just fine! Thank you for the fast anwser!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have just to inverted the price and the text:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );
function cw_change_product_price_display( $price ) {
    // Your additional text in a translatable string
    $text = __('TEXT');

    // returning the text before the price
    return $text . ' ' . $price;
}
```

This should work as you expect…

Comment: As a new question, clearly explaining things with your code attempt, as what you are asking here is not really understandable and can't be answered in a comment. Also, please remove those comments, thank you.

Comment: **Thank you, I asked a new question**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77031759/add-a-custom-text-before-the-price-display-in-woocommerce-in-different-sections

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
if( !function_exists("add_custom_text_prices") ) {
    function add_custom_text_prices( $price, $product ) {
        // Text
        $text_regular_price = __("Regular Price: ");
        $text_final_price = __("FinalPrice: ");

        if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
            $has_sale_text = array(
              '<del>' => '<del>' . $text_regular_price,
              '<ins>' => '<br>'.$text_final_price.'<ins>'
            );
            $return_string = str_replace(
                array_keys( $has_sale_text ), 
                array_values( $has_sale_text ), 
                $price
            );

            return $return_string;
        }
        return $text_regular_price . $price;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'add_custom_text_prices', 100, 2 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use "woocommerce_currency_symbol" hook something like this :

```
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_existing_currency_symbol', 10, 2);
function change_existing_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
  switch( $currency ) {
    case 'AUD': $currency_symbol = 'AUD$'; break;
  }
  return $currency_symbol;
}
```

hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

use this code, if you haven't price for all of your products, then text before the price will not show up!

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );
function cw_change_product_price_display( $price ) {

$text = __('text-before-price-here:');

if ($price  == true) {
return '<span class="pre-price">'. $text . '</span> ' . $price;
}
else {

}
}
```

good luck ;))