# Add a custom text to Woocommerce product availability and display it for cart items

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

I'm trying to find a way to place custom text before availability info (out of stock, in stock etc.) on woocommerce single product page.

I am using something like that:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'change_product_availability_display' ); 
add_filter( 'unknown filter', 'change_product_availability_display' );
function change_product_availability_display( $availability ) {
    // Additional text 
    $text = __('Availability:'); 
    // returning the text before the availability 
    return $text . ' ' . $availability; 
}
```

Its's based on: [Add a custom text before the price display in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47016425/add-a-custom-text-before-the-price-display-in-woocommerce).

In case of price filter named in my code "unknown filter" was `woocommerce_cart_item_price`. I've looked for this kind of filter for availability/stock item, but can't find it.

Maybe someone could review this code and help me to find this "`unknown_filter`" or have other idea how I can put custom text before availability info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have revisited your code as your are trying to merge a string with an array. 
Also I have added a 2nd hooked function that will allow to display your "labeled" availability to items in cart and checkout.

The code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'add_label_to_availability_display' );
function add_label_to_availability_display( $availability ) {
    if( is_product() || is_cart() || is_checkout() ){
        $label = __( 'Availability', 'woocommerce' ) . ': ';
        $availability['availability'] = $label . $availability['availability'];
    }
    return $availability;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'add_availability_below_cart_item_name', 10, 3);
function add_availability_below_cart_item_name( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $availability = $cart_item['data']->get_availability();
    return $item_name . '<br>' . $availability['availability'];
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme).*

Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks LoicTheAztec. Your code indeed solved my problem. Can you reccomend some good guide to woo functions/filters, because in woo official documentation you can find everything, but is rather hard to understand without context? ;) Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @Fidel2006 The way is searching first on google and on StackOverflow and after in official woocommerce docs… Test everything… use print_r() everywhere. Go in database to see how data is saved. Be curious. When you are not used to woocommerce, is difficult... You will need time to understand and get growing skills. There is no secrets: Time and energy…